# How to add a new vendor

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am new to prestashop and trying to add a 3rd party library in vendor folder which i could use in my custom module. I have added composer.json in my module as well but unable to get the 3rd party library installed in prestashop vendor folder.

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have created composer.json in my module included the library to be installed in require tag, tried by manually placing the library in vendor folder, the main thing is i am unable to access the library class. I also have tried accessing the 3rd party library by placing it in my module in libraries folder, also tried with folder name lib. But everytime i create the object of class it says the 'classname' not found.

Comment: Did you include composer's autoload.php in your module?

Answer (score 0):

I used the fzaninotto/faker library and I got it working like this :
Composer.json at the root of my module :

```
{
    "require": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.6"
    }
}
```

then run

```
composer install
```

Now in order to use this package I created a file called faker.php at the root of my module that starts with including the correct files :

```
<?php

require('vendor/autoload.php');
require('../../config/config.inc.php');

$faker = Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR');
```

Basicly this is a 3 step process :
 1. Create your composer.json
 2. Run composer install
 3. Include the autoload.php that is in the newly created vendor directory, make sure you use the correct relative path